# Mount disc Xfs filesystem

Tags: mount, filesystem, xfs

How can I mount a disc with a xfs file system?

I'm using `sudo mount /dev/sdc2 /media/mntiomega` i receive the error: `you must specify the filesystem`

Comment: Um... `sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdc2 /media/mntiomega`?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the filesystem since mount don't recognize it:

```
sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdc2 /media/mntiomega
```

That should do the trick. Also, verify that you have installed `xfsprogs` and `xfsdump` packages.